# How do I compare and Select SQL columns between tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's just say that I have a database with 2 tables as follows:

> Book (Name, Publisher) and
>
> Publisher (Name, Email)

Now I have a book called `Book A` with `publisher a` and `publisher a` with email `sth@gmx.com`.

I want the output to be `sth@gmx.com` i.e., the contact detail(s) of the publisher of said book.

Is there any way to do this if possible? I am new to `Sql Server`. So, maybe I missed something which is obvious.

Comment: Use a `join` for this. Post your table structure if you need more assistance

Comment: See my answer below and request you to vote if you found the answer helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure would be something like this (based on your explanation):

```
SELECT v.email
FROM Buch AS b
JOIN Verlag AS v
ON b.verlag = v.name 
WHERE b.name = 'Buch A';
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I need to change to suit my actual (german) fields.

My book table is called Buch and let's say I have a book with the name "Buch A".
The book has a "Name" and a "Verlag" column.

My publisher table is called Verlag and let's say I have a publisher with the name "abc" and the email "sth@gmail.com".
The publisher has a "Name" and a "Email" column.

Answer (score 0):

To combine results you should use JOIN.
In this case:

```
Select publisher.Email
From book
Inner join publisher on publisher.name = book.publisher
```

But you should really use ID's on the rows where the book should store the publishers id as a Foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are selecting email of a publisher who publishes the Book called A. Based on the above two tables and two columns in each table you may use below query provided Publisher in Book and Name in Publisher table are same.

```
  SELECT p.email FROM Publisher p JOIN Book b 
  ON b.publisher = p.name WHERE b.name = 'A';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following using `inner join`.

```
create table Book (Name Varchar(50), Publisher Varchar(50))
insert into Book Values ('Book A', 'publisher a')

Create table Publisher (Name Varchar(50), Email Varchar(50))
insert into Publisher Values('publisher a', 'sth@gmx.com')

select Publisher.Email 
FROM Publisher
inner join Book on Publisher.Name = Book.Publisher
where Book.Name = 'Book A' and Publisher.Name = 'publisher a'
```

You can learn about SQL join [**here**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

The output is as shown below

```
Email
-----------
sth@gmx.com
```

You can find the live demo [**Live Demo**](https://rextester.com/QWOG61329)